# Time interval from a constant reference time in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

Given a `df`

```
4
0
3
3
3
```

and reference ndata_time='2019-01-15 7:00:00',

I would to create a new column but with an interval of `5sec`

```
4   2019-01-15 7:00.00
0   2019-01-15 7:00.05
3   2019-01-15 7:00.10
3   2019-01-15 7:00.15
3   2019-01-15 7:00.20
```

However, I am having difficulties of setting the interval_range() function in Pandas.

Appreciate if someone can shed some light.

```
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(0)
ndata_time='2019-01-15 7:00:00'
lapse=5 # unit in second
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5,size=(5)),columns=['data'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to use [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) here. Set `period` and `freq` parameter as needed.

- [From Docs `pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)

> **periods**: int, optional
>
> - Number of periods to generate.
>
> **freq**: str or DateOffset, default ‘D’
>
> - Frequency strings can have multiples, e.g. ‘5H’. See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases) for a list of frequency aliases.

```
pd.date_range(start='2019-01-15 7:00:00', periods=5, freq='5S')

# DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-15 07:00:00', '2019-01-15 07:00:05',
#                '2019-01-15 07:00:10', '2019-01-15 07:00:15',
#                '2019-01-15 07:00:20'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='5S')
```